Liquids - does increased pressure increase "internal energy"?
I do not have much experience with working with liquids so I am basing a lot of my intuition on what I know about gases (which I have a feeling is not good, but gases are the closest thing to liquids that I feel like I understand decently :D).
I have just stumbled upon something that I can not wrap my head around. With gases we have the internal energy $U = \frac{3}{2}nk_BT = \frac{3}{2}pV$ (for monatomic gases) from the ideal gas law. Intuitively I would guess that this finding would generalise into taking a volume integral of the pressure if it is not constant (for example with a very very high cillinder with air inside, the pressure at the bottom would be higher than at the top). And I can imagine this energy transfering into a different kind of energy, for example by pushing a piston.
However, with water or ideal liquids I am not really sure. If I have a tank full of an ideal liquid that I seal on the top and apply a huge pressure on, the seal will not move (as opposed to the gas case), so I do zero work on the system? So the energy increase of the water should be zero? But in the derivation of Bernoulli's principle the pressure plays an important role and is in the end a part of the equation. There we have a term that is clearly based on the kinetic energy of the volume element ($\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$), another one based on its potential energy ($\rho g h$), and the last one on "pressure energy"(?) - I have seen it called like that.
I also feel like pressure should add some sort of energy even into incompressible liquids - if I once again had a sealed tank, made from for example glass, with the seal pointing towards the floor and the glass bottom pointing towards the sky and I applied some pressure to the seal and gradually increased it (always locking the press in place so it does not jump), eventually the glass top would break - here I would expect some shards to come flying off, with energy being delivered from (I assume) the freed pressure?
What is correct here and/or what am I missing in each of the cases (I feel like some of them contradict others, while all of them make sense to me :D)? Is the situation different in case of an ideal liquid and in the case of water (which is a tiny bit compressible)? Thanks a lot!

That liquids are "incompressible" does not mean it is impossible to compress them - it just means that it is very difficult to do so.

@NuclearHoagie Is this also the case when considering ideal liquids? I thought that a part of their definition was incompressibility, but in the sense of "no matter what you do the density does not change". As mentioned in the question, I know water can compress a tiny tiny bit, which partially resolves my confusion (I can look at it as I would on a difficult to compress gas). But I'm confused about the ideal liquid case, which is often considered.

You do not have to confuse the ideal fluids of fluidodynamics with real liquids. They are not ideal under any meaning of the word.

Look up pressure energy of liquids


However, with water or ideal liquids I am not really sure. If I have a tank full of an ideal liquid that I seal on the top and apply a huge pressure on, the seal will not move (as opposed to the gas case), so I do zero work on the system?

Correct.

So the energy increase of the water should be zero?

Correct, if it was incompressible. In reality water compresses a little, so some small work is stored in the water (much less than the so-called "pressure energy", which is actually not energy of water, but a work term).

But in the derivation of Bernoulli's principle the pressure plays an important role and is in the end a part of the equation.  There we have a term that is clearly based on the kinetic energy of the volume element ($\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$), another one based on its potential energy ($\rho g h$), and the last one on "pressure energy"(?) - I have seen it called like that.

Correct. However, the pressure term in the Bernoulli equation does not represent energy stored in the liquid element, but it represents work that will be done on this element by surrounding liquid, when the element moves from its location to another location with zero pressure. This is clear from the usual derivation of the Bernoulli equation, which considers work of pressure forces on incompressible fluid in a streamtube.

I also feel like pressure should add some sort of energy even into incompressible liquids - if I once again had a sealed tank, made from for example glass, with the seal pointing towards the floor and the glass bottom pointing towards the sky and I applied some pressure to the seal and gradually increased it (always locking the press in place so it does not jump), eventually the glass top would break - here I would expect some shards to come flying off, with energy being delivered from (I assume) the freed pressure?

In case of perfectly incompressible fluid, no - if its temperature does not change, it can't store any internal energy due to increased pressure, irrespective of value of this pressure. The kinetic energy of the shards and fluid comes from work done on them by the surrounding fluid, and this is the same as work of the source of pressure on the fluid moving elsewhere at the same time. The incompressible fluid just transfers this work from the source to the accelerated shards and fluid, the fluid in between stores no energy.
I've tried to explain this in other past answers, see here:
How is Bernoulli's equation a statement of conservation of energy?
What is the term $P$ in bernoulli's equation defined as?
What is Pressure Energy?

Just to make sure I understand it correctly: For a specific liquid element, I can consider p*V to be a part of its energy since I could (in theory) extract that energy out of it - for example by making a hole in a container and letting it shoot out (with p*V changing into 1/2*m*v^2). But if I had a tank full of water and was asked to calculate the energy of the water, it would only be the potential energy as I can not extract the additional "p*V energy" (as it is not in fact there)? And if someone asks for the "potential pressure energy" of the tank, it is a poor question?

@Pandicon No, $pV$ is not part of energy of the liquid element. We can make $pV$ arbitrarily large, without putting any energy into the incompressible element.  The energy of such element is always $\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh$. $pV$ is just a term in the Bernoulli equation which allows us to calculate this energy. The energy comes from work of the thing that moves water (piston) that has the pressure. The work does not come from the fluid itself.

@Pandicon Yes, the term pressure energy is a bad term, and any question about it insinuating it is actual energy is a bad, misconceived and deceiving question.

So while $pV$ is not a part of the energy of the element, the element will gain this amount of energy if it leaves the pressurised container? It sounds really similar to a charged particle getting repelled from another particle, where we however consider the potential energy to be a part of the energy of the particle? I must be missing a fundamental difference between these two...

@Pandicon Yes, if there is steady flow where fluid elements go from pressure $p$ to pressure zero, the elements receive work $pV$ from the pressure forces. But such element receives this work only after it is accelerated and its zero drops to zero. It does not have this energy when it still has pressure $p$.

@Pandicon Potential energy is energy of the particle or system; it can be thought of as stored either in the particle, or in the space in between and inside the particles in the system. The term $pV$ however is not energy of anything, it cannot be thought of as stored in the liquid. It is a term in the Bernoulli equation that comes from the work part of the generalized work-energy theorem, not from the energy part.

@Pandicon This work only transfers from the source of energy (potential energy of liquid above it, or the body maintaining the pressure) to the liquid elements when they change position and move downstream. While the elements have the high pressure $p$ upstream, they do not have energy $pV$; they only acquire energy $(p-p_{low})V$ after work is done on them when they get to place with lower pressure $p_{low}$. So the Bernoulli equation tells us how energy of the liquid element changes with pressure; but this energy really changes, it is not conserved.

It might help to get quantitative.
You’re asking about $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_T$, the change in internal energy induced by a pressure change at constant temperature.
From the fundamental relation, this is
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{\partial (T\,dS-P\,dV)}{\partial P}\right)_T&=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T-P\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T\\&= -T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P-P \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T\\&=-TV\alpha+\frac{PV}{K} \end{align},$$
where I’ve used a Maxwell relation and where $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient and $K$ the bulk modulus.
For the ideal gas, $\alpha=\frac{1}{T}$ and $K=P$, and there is no internal energy increase from isothermal compression; the ideal gas is not an enthalpic spring but an entropic spring, storing not strain energy but low entropy (or free energy).
For other materials, such as condensed matter, strain energy is stored as mediated by both material properties. (Incompressibility implies that $\alpha\to 0$ and $K\to\infty$, but this is an idealization; no material is truly incompressible. The bulk modulus of water, say, is around 2 GPa, much larger than that of familiar gases but much smaller than that of familiar solids.)
